# Наличие 9 бита в байте в современных компьютерах

Tags: ассемблер, битовые-операции

Вырезка из книги Питера Абеля:

> Группа  из  девяти битов представляет собой  байт; восемь
>             битов которого содержат данные и один бит -  контроль на чет
>             ность.

В нынешних компьютерах до сих пор это используется? И можно ли как-нибудь повлиять на него программно/использовать его (при его наличии) или это чисто машинная часть?

Comment: Только на аппаратном уровне.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не факт, что именно такая реализация.

Но сам принцип: хранение избыточности с целью обнаружения (и, возможно, коррекции) ошибок — да, по-прежнему используется, в чипах оперативной памяти с ECC, используемой преимущественно **на серверах**. Такая память заметно дороже, чуточку медленнее и должна поддерживаться материнской платой и процессором.

Реализация **аппаратная**: избыточность считается железкой. Коррекция, если возможна (один бит?) происходит тоже в железе, но система уведомляется об ошибке (на x86 через [machine check exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception)) и может обработать событие программно на любом уровне. Если невозможно, то происходит только уведомление.

[Linux, к примеру, резко убивает процесс, использовавший страницу с умершей памятью и не использует эту страницу в дальнейшем](https://serverfault.com/a/763335/412506).

Способы ручного доступа к избыточным битам мне неизвестны. Подозреваю, что даже если они существуют, то скорее с отладочными целями, и использоваться конечными пользователями не должны.